# Upload files to Google Drive using TCL and cURL

Tags: curl, google-drive-api, tcl

I'm working with the TCL syntax for uploading a file to a Google Drive subdirectory using cURL. Based on [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) there is a property called `parent` that holds the subfolder id. It works fine in the "Try the API section" - and my code below works fine if I remove the `parents` parameter (then, the file is uploaded to the GDrive root folder).

This is how the parameter should look like based on documentation:

```
parents : [{"id" : "0B-b5yS-0xCQjVEcyMm9hYmtqd0k"}]
```

Now I want to adapt this to my current code but it errors occur. I assume the issue is related to TCL syntax, but as I'm not that familiar with the language I'm completely lost now after spending hours with try&error to get it working. What I try to do is to set a parameter `fileMetaData` that holds all necessary values for the metadata (so even the `parent` folder list), furthermore I define a parameter `curlCommand` that stores the final cURL statement. Within that `curlCommand` I provide the `fileMetaData` and finally I execute the command with cURL within an *eval exec* statement. 
I think it is related to substitution? But I'm really lost. I've tried it with double-quotes and even with backslashes before the curly braces and the square brackets. I always get an error.

This is the current code:

```
set fileMetaData "metadata={name : '$backupFile', title : '$fileName', \
                            description : 'Backup file from $today', \
                            parents : [{id : '0B-b5yS-0xCQjVEcyMm9hYmtqd0k'}] }"

set curlCommand "-H \"GData-Version: 3.0\" \
                 -H \"Authorization: Bearer $accessToken\" \
                 -F \"$fileMetaData;type=application/json;charset=UTF-8\" \
                 -F \"file=@$backupFile\" \
                   https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart"

catch { eval exec /usr/local/addons/prtz/curl -k $curlCommand}
```

The error message I get while running the code is:

```
invalid command name "id: '0B-b5yS-0xCQjVEcyMm9hYmtqd0k'"
while executing "{id: '0B-b5yS-0xCQjVEcyMm9hYmtqd0k'}"
```

Maybe important: I strictly have to use native **TCL 8.2** without any additional libraries (i.e. for JSON support).
I appreciate any input that helps to figure how to solve!

Thanks.

Comment: 8.2 is vastly long out of support.

Comment: I know... but can't influence it. There are manufacturers out there who are still deliver their hardware with this version even in 2017.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be easiest to build that command line bit by bit with list commands.

```
# Your immediate problem was the square brackets building this value; backslash needed
set fileMetaData "{name : '$backupFile', title : '$fileName', \
                   description : 'Backup file from $today', \
                   parents : \[{id : '0B-b5yS-0xCQjVEcyMm9hYmtqd0k'}\] }"

set curlCommand {/usr/local/addons/prtz/curl -k}
lappend curlCommand -H "GData-Version: 3.0"
lappend curlCommand -H "Authorization: Bearer $accessToken"
lappend curlCommand -F "metadata=$fileMetaData;type=application/json;charset=UTF-8"
lappend curlCommand -F "file=@$backupFile"
lappend curlCommand "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart"

catch { eval exec $curlCommand }
# If you were using a supported Tcl (8.5 and later) I'd say use this instead:
#     catch { exec {*}$curlCommand }
# but since we've built with lappend there's no surprises anyway.
```

It's much easier to build lists correctly using the list commands. In this case, you could also build the metadata using `format`:

```
set parentID 0B-b5yS-0xCQjVEcyMm9hYmtqd0k
set description "Backup file from $today"

set fileMetaData [format \
        {{name : '%s', title : '%s', description : '%s', parents : [{id : '%s'}]}} \
        $backupFile $fileName $description $parentID]
```

(Another option would be `subst -nocommands`, but for this case I think `format` is neater.)

Comment: In general, I'd advise using a JSON library _if you weren't on a **very** old version of Tcl_ because that will handle “unexpected” characters (e.g., `'`) in values correctly without you having to think about it…

Comment: You'll want to quote the object keys too, for valid JSON.